# Unable to Run Python by Code Runner on Visual Studio Code on MacOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, visual-studio-code

Facing issues with Vsc Code Runner, unable to run python code using Code Runner. Works fine when clicked on Run Python Code button

I get an error

```
zsh: no such file or directory: /usr/local/bin/python3.9.2
```

I have identified the error, need to change the run command from

```
python -u
```

to

```
python3 -u
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that you have installed the python extension. Secondly, this should be caused by the error of interpreter path recognition. You can modify it manually.
Type `ctrl+shift+P` and then choose “python:select Interpreter”.
Check that the Python interpreter has selected the correct one, and then run the file again.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Code Runner extension settings, there you would find **Code-runner: Executor Map** now click on the **edit in settings.json** of it, replace `"python": "python -u"` with `"python": "python3 -u"`